# Powershell module (psm1) auto-execute function after module load

Tags: powershell, powershell-module

just AFTER a module loads (.psm1)...
I want a specific function in that module to be executed.

It is not BEFORE the loading.. it's after the loading<...>
so please do not mention (.psd1) 'ScriptsToProcess'

I know I can execute the function after from code...
but what I want is that some code executes automatically
when somebody loads/imports the module...

I try to put some code outside any function
in the module but no luck...

?can someone provide a simple example
like a module with a simple function
that runs automatically
when the module is imported to memory (Import-Module))

Comment: Please provide a clearer explanation of what you're trying to accomplish.  This sounds a lot like an X/Y problem.

Comment: just reformulated the question... please tell me if is comprehensible now...

Answer (score 4):

Any code outside of a function in the psm1 will run when the module is loaded.

Comment: Thank you, your suggestion solved a problem I was trying to overcome for hours.

Answer (score 0):

Ok... I just figured out...
after some brainstorming
and a few tests...

To contextualize the issue:

When I create a module (.psm1) in the \modules folder
(so it will be automatically scanned by powershell engine)
I was hoping that any "free code" present in the module
would be executed when powershell first "touches" the module...
(this would serve for environment initialization)

Well module loading in powershell does not works this way...
Anyway I solved the problem invoking the "wanted initialization code"
from the profile.ps1
(could be from any of the auto-invoked "profile" files)

Thanks...